# Google sheets app script fails in template until re-saved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having a weird error. I have a google sheet that has an app script so that when users check a box it also updates check boxes in another sheet. Here is a version with lots of logging turned on that isn't usually in the production version:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   logEventObject(e);
   var sheetInp1 = e.source.getSheetByName("Master-Clients");
   var sheetOut = e.source.getSheetByName("full_list");

   // Assuming checkboxes are in column 8 of Master-Clients. 
   var editedRange = e.range;
   if (editedRange.getSheet().getName() === "Master-Clients" && editedRange.getColumn() === 8) {
       var isChecked = editedRange.getValue();
       var matchingValue = sheetInp1.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), 2).getValue();
       Logger.log('matchingValue: ' + matchingValue);

       var dataOut = sheetOut.getDataRange().getValues();
       Logger.log('length: ' + dataOut.length);
       for (var i = 0; i < dataOut.length; i++) {
           if(i === 10) {
             Logger.log('check: ' + dataOut[i][1]);
             Logger.log('check2: ' + sheetOut.getRange(i + 1, 27));
           }
           if (dataOut[i][1] === matchingValue) { // Assuming matching values are in column 2 of full_list, note different numbering convention
               sheetOut.getRange(i + 1, 27).setValue(isChecked);
           }
       }
   }
}

function logEventObject(e) {
   if (e) {
       Logger.log('Range: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
       Logger.log('Value: ' + e.value);
       Logger.log('Sheet name: ' + e.range.getSheet().getName());
       // Log other properties as needed
   } else {
       Logger.log('Event object is null or undefined');
   }
}
```

This code works fine. It is saved in a template file.

Then, I use python to copy the template file and add in the latest data from our database. This is the relevant code that creates the file from the template containing the app script:

```
    copied_file = drive_service.files().copy(
        fileId=TEMPLATE_FILE,
        body={'name': new_file_name, 'parents': [folder_id]},
        supportsAllDrives=True
    ).execute()
```

Here is the problem:

1. When I open the new file, the code doesn't work. In the log, the status is failed. When I look at the cloud logs I get the message: "No logs are available for this execution
   For recent executions there may be some delay in log availability." I waited 12 hours, still no logs.
2. But, if I open the code, make any meaningless change like adding another space into a comment and then save the code, it starts working.

Any ideas on what the problem might be, or a work-around that doesn't involve asking the first user to edit the app script?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `This code works fine. It is saved in a template file.` from your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: This code works fine = there are no problems with the code. It works and delivers the expected results.

It is saved in a template file = I save the working code in a google sheet. This sheet is referenced In the next step, called TEMPLATE_FILE in the next code batch.

Comment: There is something in the action of copying the google sheet that breaks the app script. It then errors until the app script is opened and then saved.

Comment: Obvious question, but for the sake of clarity: The `onEdit` function is a `simple trigger`, right?

Comment: Yep. When you click a check box it is triggered.